# "Low Disk Space" after downloading less than 6GB of files on a 128GB Bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, memory-usage

I created a bootable usb using [the official Ubuntu tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on a 128GB flash drive. However, After booting into the Live System and downloading a little less than 6GB of files, I get the message "low disk space".

I haven't installed or downloaded anything else so I have no idea how I am already running out of space, since the flash drive is 128 gigs.

Comment: The Live system is for experiment mostly and it seems your persistent storage files system (which is used to persist files from Live session) has consumed by those downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just created an install media, which could have been done on a 2G stick.  It doesn't even look like the instructions produce an install media with persistence, so your 6G limit is probably when you run out of memory.  You can use the stick to make an install to another stick, or recreate the install media on a smaller stick, and make a full install to the 128G stick.  If you do that, search here for optimizations of a USB installation.